# VirtualHost on Lion navigates to wrong document root

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost

I'm struggling with getting Virtual Hosts running on my local Lion development machine.

Here's the scenario. I have Site-A.dev and Site-B.dev sitting in my `User/computername/Sites` folder, like this:
`User/computername/Sites/Site-A.com`
`User/computername/Sites/Site-B.com`

My `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file has the following entries:

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#       DocumentRoot /Users/computername/Sites/Site-A.com
#       ServerName project.Site-A.dev
#</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /Users/computername/Sites/Site-B.com
        ServerName project.Site-B.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

#127.0.0.1      project.Site-A.dev
127.0.0.1       project.Site-B.dev
```

**Eventhough all instances of Site-A are commented out, every time I try `http://project.Site-B.dev` I get Site-A in the browser!** What in the world is going on?

To make matters more confounding, when edit my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file to look like this:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I get a Server Not Found error!

If I leave it like:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then all I get is Site-A

What am I missing?

**Edit** It should be noted that both sites are running PHP

Answer (score 1):

After running `httpd -S` I discovered that the location of my httpd-vhosts.conf file had been moved to `/private/etc/apache2/other/httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Heres what the `httpd -S` reported:

```
[Tue Feb 07 12:51:37 2012] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using macshortname.local for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server Site-A.com (/private/etc/apache2/other/httpd-vhosts.conf:17)
         port 80 namevhost Site-A.com (/private/etc/apache2/other/httpd-vhosts.conf:17)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/private/etc/apache2/other/httpd-vhosts.conf:36)
Syntax OK
```

Once I discovered that I was editing the wrong `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I was able to fix the problem.